# RegEx for capturing a string between two substrings

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract all occurrences of a pattern in a text file (it's an Amino acid sequence from a DNA sample).

The pattern I am trying to match is MetSOMETEXT***

There are multiple occurrences of the pattern in the source string, I am trying to get all.

I am doing this in python using re.findall at the moment but it's not working.

```
orfs = re.findall('(?<=Met).*(?=\*\*\*)' , translatedSequence)
```

I'm hoping to get a list of strings containing the result.

Comment: Your code should work properly if I've understood you.

Comment: Perhaps `orfs = re.findall('(?<=Met)[^*]*(?=\*\*\*)' , translatedSequence)` Your expression is using a greedy match, `.*` which will go as far right in the string before it attempts to match `(?=\*\*\*)` My suggested change will match non `*` up to `***`

Comment: To allow `*` in the capture that are not 3 consecutive `*`, orfs = re.findall('(?<=Met).*?(?=\*\*\*)' , translatedSequence)` where `.*?` makes it a non greedy match

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to have any lookarounds to get your desired output. You can simply do that with an expression similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/skk2gx/1) maybe:

```
(Met)(.*)(\*\*\*)
```

There are three capturing groups, where the second one is your desired output.

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(Met)(.*)(\*\*\*)"

test_str = "MetSOMETEXT***"

subst = "\\1\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
MetSOMETEXT
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(Met)(.*)(\*\*\*)/gm;
const str = `MetSOMETEXT***`;
const subst = `$1$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/skk2gx/1/).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Comment: wow awesome response and totally exposing my cluelessness on this topic. Only one mod to the original question, I need to keep the "Met", the current regex seems to loose the search. I'll try a few variations to see what works.